# Javascript Reading ASP GridVIEW BoundField Column which is visible false

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView 
ID="GridView1" 
runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Width="596px" 
DataKeyNames="Key" >

<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="Key" SortExpression="key" Visible="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="StockId" HeaderText="StockId" Visible="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Freq1" HeaderText="Freq1" Visible="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Freq2" HeaderText="Freq2" Visible="False" />     

<asp:BoundField DataField="MedicineName" HeaderText="MedicineName" ReadOnly="true" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DoseQty"                                                         
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDoseQty" Text='<%# Bind("DoseQty") %>' runat="server"
        Height="23px" Width="38px" onchange="javascript:dataChange(event);" ></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="DoseUOM" HeaderText="DoseUOM" ReadOnly="true" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Duration" runat="server" Height="16px" 
            Text='<%# Bind("Duration") %>' Width="45px" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);">    </asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDuration" Text='<%# Bind("Duration") %>'  runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete All">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeaderDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete All" 
            onclick="javascript:SelectheaderCheckboxes(this)" />                                                            
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItemDelete" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            Text="Delete" onclick="javascript:SelectitemCheckboxes(this)"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Update" 
    ShowEditButton="True"                                                         
    CausesValidation="false"  />

</Columns>
```

I am using traditional JavaScript(not JQUERY) to read a value from Asp.net GridView at client site.
But after I trying several times, I found that I don't know how could I read a value from BoundField Column which is "Visile=False" ,in pure javascript.

```
var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
var OutputString = "";
if (grid.rows.length > 0) 
{
for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < grid.rows[i].cells.length; j++) 
    {
        if (j == 1) 
        {
        OutputString += "grid.rows[i].cells[" + j + "]  :" + grid.rows[i].cells[j] +
        "\ngrid.rows[i].cells[" + j + "].innerText :" + grid.rows[i].cells[j].firstChild.value;
        OutputString += "\n\n";
        } 
        else 
        {
            OutputString += "grid.rows[i].cells[" + j + "]  :" + grid.rows[i].cells[j] +
            "\ngrid.rows[i].cells[" + j + "].innerText :" + grid.rows[i].cells[j].innerText;
            OutputString += "\n\n";
        }
    }   
}
}
```

### Output

```
grid.rows[i].cells[0]  :[object]
grid.rows[i].cells[0].innerText :Abd pant XXXL

grid.rows[i].cells[1]  :[object]
grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText : 12

grid.rows[i].cells[2]  :[object]
grid.rows[i].cells[2].innerText :Pieces

grid.rows[i].cells[3]  :[object]
grid.rows[i].cells[3].innerText :1 

grid.rows[i].cells[4]  :[object]
grid.rows[i].cells[4].innerText :Delete 

grid.rows[i].cells[5]  :[object]
grid.rows[i].cells[5].innerText :Edit
```

In Javascript, is this possible to read the value from bondfield which is visible false?

**[Updated]**

All the output which I get only from Textbox template field and BoundField **which is not "Visible=False"**.

Please let me know the way, and your suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls with Visible="false" will not be rendered and therefore generate no HTML.

If you want to make your controls invisible but still reference them, first remove Visible="false" and then you could either use CSS on your controls:

```
style="display:none;"
```

Or you could hide the GridView columns (your first four BoundFields) in your RowDataBound event after they've been rendered:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[column_index].Visible = false;
}
```